# first player had to pass- points for second player?

Tags: scrabble

First player had to pass in opening the game due to drawing all consonants and had no options after searching helps on google. Would the next player get double points instead?

Comment: You're *allowed* to pass on any of your turns. But that first player also had the option to exchange.

Answer (score 6):

Yes (assuming they don't pass as well). The center square is a double word square.

From [the rules](https://www.scrabblepages.com/scrabble/rules/):

> ## The First Word Score
>
> The star is a double square and will offer a double word score.